# Get Content Size of string

Tags: c++, string, cocos2d-x

Is it possible to get `content size` of a `string` in `c++`. I'm not talking about length here. I want to place strings in a row one after the other, say on a `label` but don't want to get content size of label.I need to get space a string covers on screen.

Comment: What is *"content size"* if not the length of the string?

Comment: You could explain better with an example.

Comment: "content size" is how much space it covers on screen.

Comment: The size the "string covers on screen" is not a property of the string (at least std::string has nothing like this).

Comment: Ok! Then I must have to do something with label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask is not possible with C++ string.

May be you could use something like this, with NSString and sizeWithFont:

```
NSString *str= @"Hello, World!"
UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:11];
CGSize supposedSize = [str sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];    
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:str dimensions:supposedSize fontName:@"YourFontName" fontSize:11];
```

to find out the height and width of the text in cocos2d.